# Is there a way to make multiple instances of a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am working on a GUI app for a bike rental service, and I need that every time when **RENT A BIKE** is click a new instance of the *class customer* is created.
**below is an example of the GUI**
[image]

```
import main
from BikeGUI.ADDSTOCK.add_stock import shp

#class which I want many instances of
customer = main.Customer()
#gui class
class Rent_Bike:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
           '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.''' 

#some gui definitions
        top.geometry()
        top.title()
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
#some more gui definitions
        self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1.configure()

#more gui definitions
        self.price = tk.Entry(top)
        self.price.configure(text='''CodeName:''', .....)
        ...
        ...
        ...

#define tkinter variable
        self.num_of_bikes = tk.StringVar()
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black", textvariable=self.num_of_bikes)
        ...
        ...
        ...


    def confirm_order(self):
        #get number of bikes from entry
        customer.bikes = self.num_of_bikes.get()
        customer.rentalBasis = rent_bike_support.selected.get()
        customer.codename = self.customername.get()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

that's the class in which I want the customer object to be instantiated several times, but the problem is that it only gets instantiated once, and it overwrites all the other customers that I created before

P.S
I later need to import this customer object into another GUI file
here's how I am importing it

```
from BikeGUI.rentbike.rent_bike import customer
```

but I think the problem is not with import it to another.
[Link to my files](https://github.com/Manologk/BIKE-APP)

Comment: Making multiple instances is exactly what classes are for.

Comment: how can this be achieved is we don't know how many instances we went, most information I have found is of using a for loop, but of course only when we know the number of objects we want.

Comment: Store them in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new instance of customers class each time when the 'Rent A Bike' button is clicked. Use the 'command' parameter in the `Button` widget and set it to the class name.

For eg: if your class name is `foo` then it should be something like this: `Button(root, text='Rent A Bike', command=foo)`. If you want to append each new instance to a list then use `lambda` function something like this `command=lambda :lst.append(foo())`.

Here is an example of instantiating a class within the same file:

```py
from tkinter import *
import new_2

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.label = Label(self.root, text='Customer')
        self.label.pack()

class foo:
     def __init__(self):
        print('Hello')
        
def print_lst():
    print(lst)

root = Tk()

lst = []

btn = Button(root, text='Rent A Bike', command=lambda :lst.append(Customer(root)) or print_lst())
#btn = Button(root, text='Rent A Bike', command=lambda :lst.append(foo()) or print_lst())
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

To create an object for a class in another file, just import that class and follow the same procedure as above

Comment: I have tried for hours to wrap my head around it all but to no avail.
so, here's the thing, allow me to put it like this,
I want to find out how I can make several objects of one class in another file, and use all the made objects in other files as well.

Comment: in your code above, for objects of Customer are windows, correct?

Comment: @EmmanuelManoloSiame when do you want to create a new object on click of a button widget?  If you want to access objects in other classes, you can pass the list to other classes as well. I didn't get what you meant by " for objects of Customer are windows "

Comment: I'd like for the objects to be created when the btn RENT A BIKE created, but I've already assigned a function that opens up a new window where the customer enters some values, lemme try to add more than one command to the button and ee what happens

Answer (score 1):

If your class is called `Rent_Bike` then you instantiate it with `instance = Rent_Bike()`.  You can do this as many times as you want.  An instance of a class is called an object.

Comment: the class of which I want multiple instances of is in the MAIN.PY
the one which I've imported at the top.
the class is called Customer()